# (Solved)No mudule named "open_clip.tokenizer" and "xformers" when using stable diffusion

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui.git/': Recv failure: Connection was reset
venv "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Commit hash: 0cc0ee1bcb4c24a8c9715f66cede06601bfc00c8
Installing requirements for Web UI
Launching Web UI with arguments:
No module 'xformers'. Proceeding without it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 361, in 
start()
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 352, in start
import webui
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\webui.py", line 16, in 
from modules import extra_networks_hypernet, ui_extra_networks_hypernets, ui_extra_networks_textual_inversion
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\extra_networks_hypernet.py", line 2, in 
from modules.hypernetworks import hypernetwork
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\hypernetworks\hypernetwork.py", line 15, in 
from modules import devices, processing, sd_models, shared, sd_samplers, hashes, sd_hijack_checkpoint
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\processing.py", line 15, in 
import modules.sd_hijack
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\sd_hijack.py", line 9, in 
from modules import sd_hijack_clip, sd_hijack_open_clip, sd_hijack_unet, sd_hijack_xlmr, xlmr
File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\sd_hijack_open_clip.py", line 1, in 
import open_clip.tokenizer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'open_clip.tokenize

when i click the stable-diffusion-webui\webui-user it appear to this.

Already solve it

Comment: Please use text formatting, and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

checking your folder:`venv\Lib\site-packages\open_clip`

if there has folders like docs, src, tests…………

replace all of them with file in `src\open_clip\`, it means you will have `venv\Lib\site-packages\open_clip\tokenizer.py`

Comment: Already up to date.
venv "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Commit hash: 0cc0ee1bcb4c24a8c9715f66cede06601bfc00c8
Installing requirements for Web UI
Launching Web UI with arguments:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from .tokenizer import HFTokenizer, tokenize
  File "D:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\open_clip\tokenizer.py", line 11, in <module>
    import ftfy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ftfy'

Comment: sorry, I haven't encountered the situation you mentioned

Comment: already solve it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

it means you git cloned open_clip, not installed open_clip.
you should `pip install git+https://github.com/mlfoundations/open_clip.git --prefer-binary`

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mlfoundations/open_clip.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21058 ms: Couldn't connect to server
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/mlfoundations/open_clip.git 'C:\Users\Ernie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-kr94d6ow' did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 128
  ╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: already solve it thanks :)